# How to fix too few arguments in wcstok?

Tags: c

I don’t understand why the compilation error occurs; it writes:

> Too few arguments to wcsdup. text->text[i] - pointer to a sentence.

```c
#include "repeat_words.h"

void repeat_words(struct Text* text)
{
    int cntRepeatWords = -1;
    int idx;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < text->cntSentence; i++)
    {
        wchar_t *istr = wcstok(text->text[i], L" "); // error
        while (istr != NULL)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < wcslen(text->text[i]); k++)
            {
                if (wcscmp(text->text[i][k], istr) == 0)
                    cntRepeatWords++;
            }
            istr = wcstok(NULL, text->text[i]); // error
        }
    }
    if (cntRepeatWords >= 3)
    {
    
    }
}
```

Comment: As for `wcstok`, please see e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcstok). You do indeed have too few arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What OS?  Because [Microsoft Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strtok-strtok-l-wcstok-wcstok-l-mbstok-mbstok-l?view=msvc-170):  "The two argument version of `wcstok` isn't standard. If you need to use that version, you'll need to define `_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_WCSTOK` before you `#include <wchar.h>` (or `#include <string.h>`)."